# Android if I use WebView.destroy() can I restore it later?

Tags: java, android, webview

So my question is simple if I use the WebView.destroy() in my app can I restore WebView to it's original state when the app was first initialize with out closing my app and opening it again? and how can I do this? I just want to be able to press a button and have this button rebuild my WebView and load a new url. I need to destroy it no just set it GONE or INVISIBLE.
Thanks

UPDATE:

```
Button rbesatbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrbesa);
                    rbesatbtn.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                                        wvr.destroy()


                        }
                    }); 
Button resttbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrrest);
                    rrestbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
 WebView wvr = new WebView(this);
 setContentView(wvr);
 wvr = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wVradios);
 wvr.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 wvr.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
 wvr.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 wvr.setInitialScale(1);
 wvr.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 wvr.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    });
```

Comment: Do you remember sorting this issue? I am in same situation, new instance of webview is not rendering.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says:

> Destroy the internal state of the WebView. This method should be called after the WebView has been removed from the view system. **No other methods may be called on a WebView after destroy.**

So I guess that the answer is no. However, you can always initialize a new one...

Comment: This sounds good, but I have been trying it, and can't get it to work, jus to try it I have set a button to destroy it and another to build a new one but it's not working, here is what I have try maybe you can see whats my problem, thanks. see the update in post.

Comment: I assume that "R.id.wVradios" is the web view you have called destroy on, right? so you can never access it again. Right now, the moment you called setContentView with another view, you old layout is destroyed so you cant get it again with findViewById. If you want to restore it, I guess you could re call setContextView(R.layout.your_layout);

Comment: What about if I use wvr.removeAllViews(); that does what I want too but when I go back to it nothing is shown, so using that can I rebuilt the wvr(web view)?